# Angularjs - Move service code to another file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am having code like,

```
<script> 
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['mc.resizer','chart.js'])
MyApp.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, $http,MyService) {
        MyService.EnvDetails().then(function success(data){
            $scope.httpdata = data;
            }, function error(err){
                console.log("error found"); return err; 
            });
});
</script>
```

And Trying to save service code in another javascript file in another folder which is like,

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
MyApp.service('MyService', function($http) {
    this.EnvDetails = function() {
         return $http({
                    url: '/myurl'                    
        }).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                //Some Code
                return //Some;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {                
                return response;
            }
        );
    };  
});
```

Saving this code in "MyService.js" and referring this file in  as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/MyService.js"></script>
```

This is giving me error,

> angular.js:11607 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   getEnvDetailsServiceProvider <- getEnvDetailsService <- Ctrl1

But when i put Service code in same file (except the first line, var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);) , along with controller code, it works. I am clueless, where i am missing the reference. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are saving to another file, no need to add the modular declaration again,

remove the dependencies

```
//remove this line var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
MyApp.service('MyService', function($http) {
    this.EnvDetails = function() {
         return $http({
                    url: '/myurl'                    
        }).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                //Some Code
                return //Some;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {                
                return response;
            }
        );
    };  
});
```

Comment: Did as suggested, but still getting error. angular.js:11607 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MyServiceProvider <- MyService <- Ctrl1

Comment: have you included the reference in the html?

Comment: I missed that, but after enabling it, now i am getting two errors. 1.Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined at MyService.js:1. And 2.angular.js:11607 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MyServiceProvider <- MyService <- Ctrl1

Comment: can you post the order which you have refered

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/resizer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/MyService.js"></script>

Comment: where is the reference for module and controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153599/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-sand).

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
```

This line CREATES new module. You should invoke this only once.
In other files just use:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp");
```

To get currently existing module.